# Do native speakers ever make pronunciation mistakes?

Tags: pronunciation

I've been thinking of this and I'd appreciate if a native speaker could reply.

Many times I see on the internet lots of English-related material about how to pronounce correctly, and that is mainly because in English you don't pronounce words as you write them.

I know that pronouncing a word correctly is an issue (sometimes unnoticed) to many students and even to advanced ones I would just like for a native speaker to share their insights on the matter and how/if this has been an issue to them.

Comment: Lots of native English speakers make mistakes in pronunciation. On the other hand, there are lots of would-be pretentious snobs on the internet who "correct" pronunciations which are not generally considered wrong.

Comment: Yes. For rare words that someone has only seen written, but has not heard pronounced.

Comment: Occasionally, even amongst native speakers there is controversy about how to pronounce words correctly. That's CON-troversy, with the principal stress on the first syllable and the secondary stress on the third.

Comment: Every single speaker of every single language in the world makes mistakes when speaking—that goes for both pronunciation, vocabulary, grammar, syntax, everything. Our brains can’t always quite keep up with our talking speed, and so we accidentally say _youthful_ instead of _useful_, or _carrot_ instead of _cucumber_ (I do that all the time, so annoying!), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Some native English speakers make *systematic errors* in pronouncing specific words, mostly out of habit.  One example is "nuclear" which some people pronounce as "NUK-u-lar" instead of "NUK-lee-ar". (Former U.S. President George W. Bush made this mistake habitually.) This error is a type of transposition and substitution of syllables.

Another example where I have been guilty of mispronunciation: "amphitheater", which I pronounced as "amp-leh-thee-a-ter" instead of "am-fee-thee-a-ter".  Essentially, I was mimicking the pronunciation of "amplification", a related concept if we think about a theater where we can hear clearly the sounds from the stage.

EDIT:
Other pronunciation error might be seen as *abbreviations*.  For example, some people pronounce "business" as "BID-ness" or "BIH-ness" instead of "BIZ-ness".

Comment: Thanks! It's interesting, I guess some difficulties come from analogy with the structure of other words (like your "amplitheater") while others might be due to the sounds themselves. I don't have trouble with "nuclear," but "anemone" really trips me up for some reason.

Comment: When my daughter was in a high school play, the director/teacher insisted that Persephone is pronounced "PER se fone" instead of "Per SEF en ee." When the students tried to correct her, she modified it slightly to "PAIR se fone," and she wouldn't budge. By the end of that play, I wanted to scream! (Actually, right from the start. It was maddening.)

Comment: _nuclear_ is the example I was thinking of, too.

Answer (score 0):

In Britain particularly, it is usually impossible to know the correct pronunciation of a place name from its spelling. If you know IPA then here's a partial list to bamboozle you.

[List of places in England with counterintuitive pronunciations: A–L](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_places_in_England_with_counterintuitive_pronunciations:_A%E2%80%93L)

To a lesser extent this is true of surnames.

Here's another list. *(Note that it is specifically American English)*

[100 Most Often Mispronounced Words and Phrases in English](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/style-and-usage/mispron.html)

Comment: And that second list is exactly what I was referring about "pretentious snobs on the internet who 'correct' pronunciations which are not generally considered wrong." He wants us to pronounce the *'l'* in *yolk*. Does he want us to put *'l'* in *folk, walk, talk, palm, calm* as well? (Some Americans put it into some of these words, but most of us don't.)

Comment: @PeterShor: I also like (read: disagree with) that list-writer's take on *arctic, chomp at the bit, February, federal, forte, a whole nother, parliament, stomp, whet*...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this happens regularly even for native speakers, particularly when we've learned particular words by reading them first, instead of *hearing* them first.  I have used words I can write, and that I know the meaning of, that I still pronounce incorrectly.

You'll often see this issue in native speakers that are voracious readers as kids--they've picked up words from novels or the internet, but the people around them aren't as into reading, and don't use the words often enough for the child to learn the correct pronunciation. Or sometimes the word is pronounced so differently from the way it looks that they might have heard it, but didn't realize it at the time.

When I first learned "lyrics" I pronounced it incorrectly.  (Lye-riks vs. leer-riks)  Likewise, "deprecated".  I pronounced it like "dee-pree-shee-ay-ted", but it's "dep-rih-kay-ted".

Comment: Note: _depreciate_ is a different word from _deprecate_, though their meanings are somewhat similar (and in one sense they can be used interchangeably).

Comment: Welp, I just looked it up and it looks like I had some unholy mixup of the meanings, spellings, and pronunciation. Although it does support my point that native speakers get stuff wrong! :)

Comment: Not at all an uncommon one, either.